# Unable find the locators sometimes in firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have recently started learning selenium with python. when I am trying to automate a page , sometimes it is working fine and most of the time it showing error. i.e

> "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: [name="passCount"]

"
how can I solve this  problem and  my Firefox is-->76.0.1 (64-bit)

please help in solving this problem, Thanks

Code:

```
passengers=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("passCount")) 
passengers.select_by_index(3) print("No of passengers selected!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: Try to add webdriverwait and check if element is visible before clicking or performing any action on desired element.  Give us more details like which language your using and post your work

Comment: Hey Amruta Pande, Thanks will try with webdriverwait, yeah so here I am using selenium with python.   Code goes like this-----passengers=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("passCount"))
passengers.select_by_index(3)
print("No of passengers selected!!!!!!!!!!").This worked for the very first and second time, when I executed it.

Comment: Can you check NAme after page refresh or when you login second time is it same? Also check do you need to perform click  action before selecting options from dropdown ?  if  find_element_by_name is not working can you try by CSS selector? or javascriptexecutor? if you need further help it would be good practice to also post DOM orHTML source for us to identify the problem